# How are the values of android.graphics.Matrix used?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, orientation

I am trying to understand how the 9 values in the android.graphics.Matrix class are used to render something (specifically a Bitmap).

I saw the defines for the 9 indices into the value array, however the naming convention did not seem to make much sense to me.

I have my own orientation system that I am using for all my objects in my engine. For me an orientation consists of a position, a forward vector, and a left vector.

I am trying to figure out how to take these 3 pieces of data (which are already mapped to screen space) and create an android.graphics.Matrix that will render my object's bitmap as I would expect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I eventually figured out the documentation. For anyone who was confused about the wording like I was, here is another explanation:

[0,0    0,1    0,2]

[1,0    1,1    1,2]

[2,0    2,1    2,2]

=

[MSCALE_X     MSKEW_X      MTRANS_X]

[MSKEW_Y      MSCALE_Y     MTRANS_Y]

[MPERSP_0     MPERSP_1     MPERSP_2]

=

[scale.x  diagonal.x  pos.x]

[diagonal.y     scale.y     pos.y]

[0.0f       0.0f       1.0f]